# How can I duplicate this JS variable and change the text used?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have the following piece of JS which helps build a basic news page with a filter from a mySQL database. It created the heading, main copy and date created, I also need to add a "read more" link at the bottom for each news item that is created, the link will be the same as the link in the heading, but will need to say "read more" instead of using the heading.

Updated - working:

```
var base_href = '/go/media~';
 function makeTable(data) {

    var tbl_body = "";
    $.each(data, function (index, row) {
            var tbl_row = "";
            $.each(row, function (k, v) {
                    if(k == 'heading' && 'id' in row) {
                            v = '<h2><a class="news" href="' + base_href + row.id +'">' + v + '</a></h2>';
                    }
                    tbl_row += "<div class='row'><div class='col-md-8 col-md-offset-2'>"
                            + v + "   </div></div>";

            });
            tbl_footer = '<a href="' + base_href + row.id + '">read more</a>';
            tbl_body += "<div class='non-white-media'>" + tbl_row + tbl_footer + "</div>";

    });
    return tbl_body;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you not just create a `tbl-footer`. Something on the lines of this

```
tbl_footer += "<a href="+data.url+">read more</a>";
...
tbl_body += "<div class='non-white'>" + tbl_row + "<br />" + tbl_footer + "</div>";
```

You have the data come back from your SQL database, the data that is return't most hold something that is related to where the article is on your web server.

My code is just a shot at what you may have inside of data, but that should help you out.

Update

```
tbl_footer = "<a href=" + base_href + row.id + ">read more</a>"; 
tbl_body = "<div class='non-white-media'>" + tbl_row + " <br /> " + tbl_footer + "</div>";
```

simple jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/qeLkq0rb/ this code will not work for you because I have updated some values to be hard coded, it is just showing you how to get your code working :)

Comment: Thanks, I tried what you suggested, I've updated my question, but it stops everything from displaying.

Comment: @Rob88991 I have probably messed up my code :) sorry about that. try this for the footer `"<a href="+data.url+">read more</a>"`

Comment: Try `tbl_footer = "<a href="' + base_href + row.id + '">read more</a>";
            tbl_body = "<div class='non-white-media'>" + tbl_row + "</div>";`, Also you need to add `tbl_footer` to your `tbl_body`

Comment: Thank you, its working now, I updated the code above to reflect it. Cheers!!